# C# PHP style array keys

Tags: c#, arrays, string, key

I have a string array:

```
String[] array1 = new String[10];
```

Is there anyway I can use keys which are nto numbers?

```
array["keyhere"] instead of array1[1]
```

anyone know how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

For example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

myDictionary.Add("key", "value");

string foo = myDictionary["key"];
```

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` has some methods that you might find useful, such as [`ContainsKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary

```
Dictionary<String,Object> phpArray = new Dictionary<String,Object>();
phpArray.Add("keyhere",1);
MessageBox.Show(phpArray["keyhere"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP arrays are called associative arrays. You can use either a Dictionary or HashMap to implement the same thing in C#.